# PouchDB callbacks never invoked

Tags: typescript, pouchdb

I don't seem to be able to get any callbacks executed with pouchdb. Any ideas what could be wrong when following code is being executed? How to catch other problems that might be occuring? I am using indexedDB on Chrome:

```
let databaseToQuery = new PouchDB('some_db');
databaseToQuery.info().then(
  info => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(info));
  }).catch((error) => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
  });
```

Any comments appreciated!

Comment: Do you get any console errors or anything like that?

Comment: No, I am not getting any logs, none of the console.log code is being executed.

Comment: Same Problem here with PouchDB 7.2.2 in Chrome browser. Problem occurs only inside our app, a pure javascript fiddle without our apps complex code works fine in the same browser instance. Don't know how to fix this. Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I found the root cause of this problem. When opening chrome://indexeddb-internals/ in your current chrome instance you will see that the affected database has pending opens/deletes > 0. This may be caused by any uncommitted transaction on that db. May be you tried to delete/destroy the db but that operation was not completly finished. This lets your PouchDB instance (and all other local PocuhDB instances) hang in the initialization phase.

Try to restart your browser instance and the issue should disappear.

Would be great if someone at PouchDB could implement a timeout observer when accessing the indexedDB for the first time. The observer should fire the error callback when indexedDB.open() doesn't respond within a certain amount of time (e.g. 10 seconds). This would help developers to find the root cause instead of debugging why the PouchDB promises get never resolved.